# Excel on Mac using commas to represent decimals

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2004 for Mac Version 11.2 on Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger) right now.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it insists on using commas to represent decimal places.  Does anyone know how to change this to periods?

Comment: Sounds to me like a localization problem. I.e. in Europe, a dot is used, in american language setting a comma. Not sure how to change it though..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to:

```
System Preferences -> International -> Input Menu
```

Check off

```
Show input menu in menu bar
```

Look up in the menu bar, and make sure the country selected is correct for you ( Assuming US ). If it's set for a different country, you may see this issue. I believe if your input is set to German, for example, it will exhibit what you describe seeing in Excel.

**EDIT**: details on solution from @sixtyfootersdude:

> This is what my international panel
>   looks like. You can see that there is
>   a little warning there. Here is what
>   resolved the problem:
>
> I changed the Region to US I closed
>   the panel I opened excel (everything
>   is now using periods) I quit excel I
>   reopened the international panel I
>   changed the region back to Canada
>   Apparently this solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help.  Your answer helped me to figure out how to solve this.  If you copy and paste my answer into yours I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite):
System preferences -> Language and Region -> Region: United Kingdom (or another country that uses dots to represent decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

This is what my international panel looks like.  You can see that there is a little warning there.  Here is what resolved the problem:

1. I changed the Region to US
2. I closed the panel
3. I opened excel (everything is now using periods)
4. I quit excel
5. I reopened the international panel
6. I changed the region back to Canada

Apparently this solves the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 on MacOS Sierra.
I can change semicolons to commas successfully by doing  the following steps:

1. Quit all Microsoft Office Application
2. Open System Preference
3. Select Language & Region
4. When the Language & Region Panel appears you change Region to United State (Computer)
5. Open Microsoft Excel and type any formula. You will see the semicolon in the formula changes to commas.

[image]

Comment: This works but I am forced to use US as region.